# Objectivist Aesthetics and the Jungian Archetypes

Tags: ayn-rand, jung

Rand and Piekoff talk a lot about romantic art.

They talk about how art symbolises metaphysical and ethical values and ideals (I believe).

They also talk about art relating to people based on their values.

I saw a talk between Jordan Peterson and some Rand philosophers. He raised a point where for a lot of people - especially those that are hurt or confused - using symbolic narratives and Jungian archetypes, helps them understand, take action and solve very serious life problems.

My question is, is there a relation between how Rand and Piekoff describe romantic art and relatable symbolic archetypes?

Comment: Hello, I very much like the gist of the question - even if I am not qualified to answer it - but I would like to ask you to kind of clarify the question: Are you asking for "relations", e.g. a similar psychological or argumental function stated within the corresponding theories, or rather for material similarities between the *descriptions* of Jungian symbolic archetypes and Rand's/Piekoff's symbolic pieces of arts? This may be important since the former has more philosophical weight while the latter (still on-topic) aspect would probably be an expression of similar cultural backgrounds.

Comment: I guess I should have elaborated a bit better: I meant Rand's objectivist aesthetics and if the effect or relateability or how it helps people understand metaphysics or ethics better... and is it a similar effect to Jungian shadow, archetypes that are somehow so instantly relatable to people.

Comment: I'm thinking about formulating this into a more complete answer (it could easily be a book). I would argue that not only was she trying to present such archetypes using her fictional work to be both practical and inspirational but she was also trying to drag a culture heading in the opposite direction along with her kicking and screaming.